# Override the cut/paste shortcut keys in Excel using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Can the cut/paste shortcut keys (ctrl+x, ctrl+v) be overridden in VBA (or through some other way within Excel) to only cut and paste values and text properties, but not fill or borders? Paste-special doesn't work with cut afaik, but I also have code running after each change that makes manual paste-special unusable (afaik) anyway. For reference - though I doubt it matters - the code I have running is to play chess on a toroidal board with a half-twist. Again, my question isn't about that, but if it would help to see it I can paste it in. It is worksheet-change.

Comment: How about pasting values and clearing the contents of the original cell?

Comment: That's essentially how we've been playing, manually erasing, retyping, and changing the font color when necessary. I'm just interested in the programming side of it, QoL, to see if I can make it feel smoother.

Comment: For anyone that comes across this, apparently I ended up using a workaround somewhat similar to Xlsx's reply above, where on cut I moved the value and font color to another square, then assigned that to the new square upon pasting. Since it was just to play toroidal chess, this worked fine with the added benefit of displaying the last move. Probably not so useful in general though.

Answer (score 0):

Lapid Palid,

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Updated: Check to see if clipboard has data, if not message and Exit

You can do it by creating a macro in a new module:

```
'                         +-------------------------+             +----------+
'-------------------------|   Sub PasteasValue()    |-------------| 04/29/21 |
'                         +-------------------------+             +----------+
' Shortcut Key: Ctrl+Shift+V

Sub PasteasValue()

  Dim vCBFmts As Variant

'*** Test to see if there is data on the clipboard ***
   vCBFmts = Application.ClipboardFormats
   If UBound(vCBFmts) < 2 Then
     MsgBox "There is no data on the cliboard!", _
            vbOKOnly + vbCritical, _
            "Error: No Data to Import"
     Exit Sub
   End If

  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub 'PasteasValue()
```

Then back in your workbook press Alt+F8, select the macro, Click Options and assign v as the shortcut.

Note: I didn't think this would work if pasting from other than Excel do to the use of Selection. However, I tested copying some red text from Word into Excel and it still worked.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the greeting and the response, but when I try it the code fails, Developer>Insert>Module>paste in the above code. Still, the response is much appreciated, will further research the commands here

Comment: Lapid, exactly what version of Excel are you using? I'm on Excel 365 and there is no Developer>Insert>Module selection. You should use Alt+F11 to get to the Visual Basic Editor. BTW: did you remember to assign Ctrl+v to the macro? I just tried the whole process again on another machine and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yah, that's weird, I'm on 365 too. Yah, did the reassignment. Alt+F8 and Alt+F11 have no effect on my computer - maybe that's my problem. So yah, Open Excel > Developer Tab > Visual Basic opens the "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications" window. Then I either go Insert > Module or right click on Sheet1 > Insert > Module, put the code in Book1 - Module1 (Code), says (General) (Declarations) at the top, then (Declarations) changes to PasteasValue. Then open Macros > Options and change the short cut to (ctrl) v, push okay. Then I can either "Run" or just close the window, both err on use.

Comment: "Run-time error '1004': PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

Comment: Got it. lol. https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/2/26/caution-creating-creating-pastespecial-macros same thing happens if I ctrl+v without ctrl+c first. Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all with ctrl+x yet. Will keep trying. Thanks for the pointers man, big help in the right direction.

Comment: Lapid, answer updated to check to see if there is data on the clipboard. HTH